# unsatisified link error

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I have written a java program to access the methods in dll.
When i execute my program from command prompt, it is getting executed properly and i am getting required output. 
But when I integrate it in my project and executed in Netbeans,I am getting following exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   ccapplication.prog1.LoadDll()Z    
> at ccapplication.prog1.LoadDll(Native
>   Method)   
> at ccapplication.prog1.main(prog1.java:19)
>  Java Result: 1

Help me...

Comment: That means that you haven't put the DLL in the place where NetBeans can find it ... OR ... you haven't told NetBeans to look for the DLL in the place where you put it.

Comment: Your link helped me in solving the problem.Thank you very much Stephen......

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass DLL file path to the java process like

```
java -Djava.library.path=<pathtoDLL> com.yourpackage.Class1
```